# Find minimum in a list of tuple among those tuples whose first elements are within a specific range

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples, minimum, bin

I have a list of tuples as follows:

```
list = [(9.9394, 0.9924), (9.8428, 0.6171), (9.9023, 0.5584), (9.8369, 1.0), (9.2106, 0.5339), (9.9748, 0.7131), (9.3257, 0.02725), (11.2865, 0.849), (10.4556, 0.7542), (10.1655, 0.9792), (10.3677, 0.5712), (10.5253, 0.8986), (10.5186, 0.5215)]
```

I want to make another list made of 7 elements in which each element is the minimum value among `list`'s second elements whose first elements are within a specific range.

The first element would correspond to bin (8.0,8.6), the second element would correspond to bin (8.6,9.2), the third element to bin (9.2,9.8), the fourth to bin (9.8,10.4), the fifth to bin (10.4,11.0), the sixth to bin (11.0,11.6), and finally the seventh to bin (11.6,12.2) all corresponding to the first elements of tuples in `list`.

Example: the fourth element would correspond to the fourth bin (9.8,10.4). There are 7 tuples in `list` whose first elements lie within this range:

(9.9394, 0.9924), (9.8428, 0.6171), (9.9023, 0.5584), (9.8369, 1.0), (9.2106, 0.5339), (9.9748, 0.7131), (9.3257, 0.02725)

So, my 4th element of the new list should be the minimum among second elements:

0.9924, 0.6171, 0.5584, 1.0, 0.5339, 0.7131, 0.02725

which is 0.02725

Is there any shorter version of the following code to establish all seven elements and hence the new list of minima in this manner? The shortest answer will be accepted.

```
dm7=0.6
item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7 = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
set1, set2, set3, set4, set5, set6, set7 = [], [], [], [], [], [], []
list = [(9.9394, 0.9924), (9.8428, 0.6171), (9.9023, 0.5584), (9.8369, 1.0), (9.2106, 0.5339), (9.9748, 0.7131), (9.3257, 0.02725), (11.2865, 0.849), (10.4556, 0.7542), (10.1655, 0.9792), (10.3677, 0.5712), (10.5253, 0.8986), (10.5186, 0.5215)]

for item in list:
    if (8. +  0*dm7 <= item[0] <= 8. +  1*dm7):
        set1.append(item[1]) 
        item1 = min(set1)
    elif (8. +  1*dm7 <= item[0] <= 8. +  2*dm7):
        set2.append(item[1])
        item2 = min(set2)
    elif (8. +  2*dm7 <= item[0] <= 8. +  3*dm7):
        set3.append(item[1])
        item3 = min(set3)
    elif (8. +  3*dm7 <= item[0] <= 8. +  4*dm7):
        set4.append(item[1])
        item4 = min(set4)
    elif (8. +  4*dm7 <= item[0] <= 8. +  5*dm7):
        set5.append(item[1])
        item5 = min(set5)
    elif (8. +  5*dm7 <= item[0] <= 8. +  6*dm7):
        set6.append(item[1])
        item6 = min(set6)
    elif (8. +  6*dm7 <= item[0] <= 8. +  7*dm7):
        set7.append(item[1])
        item7 = min(set7)

new_list = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7]
```

Comment: Which language are you trying to code this in? Please add the corresponding tag for that.

Comment: Also, what have you tried? I have a solution for you, but I'm averse to solving a "Homework" problem if you haven't given it a shot.

Comment: OK, thanks, I am adding it now. btw, it's not homework. I am just learning python on my own.

Comment: Oh, wait! I just had an issue with indices. Now, I am producing the result. However, will be happy to get a shorter version of the code.

Comment: Ok, since you're learning. Take a look at the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/bisect.html) module. I think it'll effectively solve your scenario. Scalable solution. Basically set your bin thresholds as your "breakpoints" from the example. You can create a list of sets with the index matching the bin number.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with, assuming I understand your scenario.

```
from bisect import bisect

items = [(9.9394, 0.9924), (9.8428, 0.6171), (9.9023, 0.5584), (9.8369, 1.0), (9.2106, 0.5339), (9.9748, 0.7131), (9.3257, 0.02725), (11.2865, 0.849), (10.4556, 0.7542), (10.1655, 0.9792), (10.3677, 0.5712), (10.5253, 0.8986), (10.5186, 0.5215)]

thresholds = [x / 10 for x in range(80, 123, 6)] # [8.0, 8.6, 9.2, 9.8, 10.4, 11.0, 11.6, 12.2]
bins = [list() for _ in range(len(thresholds) - 1)] # Set number of bins to 1 less than threshold points

for sorting_key, value in items: # Iterate over items to place into respective bin
    bins[bisect(thresholds, sorting_key) - 1].append(value)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(bins)
```

To which the output would be:

```
[[],
 [],
 [0.5339, 0.02725],
 [0.9924, 0.6171, 0.5584, 1.0, 0.7131, 0.9792, 0.5712],
 [0.7542, 0.8986, 0.5215],
 [0.849],
 []]
```

If you needed to get the minimum value, just use the built-in [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) function on each.

```
min_each = [min(b) if b else None for b in bins] # [None, None, 0.02725, 0.5584, 0.5215, 0.849, None]
```

In the above code, I'm not using `map(min, bins)` since `min()` cannot operate on empty lists.

Comment: And then we must choose the minimum value among each subset. Can you add that too?

Comment: This is interesting,

Comment: @Allan, Updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy` for a performance boost. With [`numpy.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) you can compute the group to which each item belongs. Then with some reshaping you can compute the minimum for each group.

```
import numpy as np


items = [(9.9394, 0.9924), (9.8428, 0.6171), (9.9023, 0.5584), (9.8369, 1.0), (9.2106, 0.5339), (9.9748, 0.7131), (9.3257, 0.02725), (11.2865, 0.849), (10.4556, 0.7542), (10.1655, 0.9792), (10.3677, 0.5712), (10.5253, 0.8986), (10.5186, 0.5215)]
items = np.asarray(items)

bins = np.linspace(8.0, 12.2, 8)
indices = np.digitize(items[:, 0], bins)  # Check which item corresponds to which bin.
mask = np.tile(indices, (bins.size, 1)) == np.arange(bins.size)[:, None]  # For each group check the members.

result = np.where(mask, items[:, 1], np.inf).min(axis=1)
result[result == np.inf] = 0  # Set default value if no items are available for that group.

print('result: ', result)
```

Comment: Thanks a_guest, it's nice! I like it,